# Does apt-get work to install Clojure on Linux (ubuntu 10)?

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, installation

I noticed that there is a package repo for Clojure, so I tried

```
sudo apt-get install clojure
```

However, the install failed, it looks like there is a java dependency missing.

I have java installed correctly on my machine: `javac -version` results 1.6.0_26.

In any case, I find leiningan is always an easy way to go, but thought I would try apt-get to see if it was working. Any thoughts on this error message?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 clojure : Depends: libasm3-java but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Clojure on Ubuntu 10.04 from Github repo with no clojure.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983427/how-to-install-clojure-on-ubuntu-10-04-from-github-repo-with-no-clojure-jar)

Comment: Are you on ubuntu 10.10? It installs without problems on Ubuntu 10.04. However I would strongly **recommend against** installing clojure from the repos - In ubuntu 10.10 the version shipped is clojure 1.1.0, the current version of clojure is 1.3.0. Clojure evolves pretty fast so to stay up to date leiningen is a much better option.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

**Yes, apt-get works** –

... BUT it it is **not** the preferred way to install Clojure.

**So ... whats the "right" way to install Clojure ?**

*Leiningen* remains the up-to-date, conventional way to rapidly get a Clojure installation up and running.

**The steps are as follows :**

1. copying this shell script: https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
2. moving it to `/usr/local/bin`
3. calling `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lein`.

Make sure you have Java installed first, of course.

These steps will install Clojure on any platform with the latest version.

Comment: Note that you can do this without `sudo` privileges, by placing it in your `~/bin` directory (or any other directory on your `PATH`).

Comment: "it it is not the preferred way to install Clojure." Can you explain why?

Comment: If I have installed Clojure using apt-get, how do I remove it completely and re-install using this method making sure, nothing clashes ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar To fully remove lein as installed via apt-get use:
`sudo apt-get purge lein`

Answer (score 7):

Just a no-brainer script to install leiningen:

```
cd `mktemp -d`
wget https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
chmod +x lein 
sudo mv lein /usr/local/bin/
lein help
cd -
```

Answer (score 6):

`apt-get install leiningen` works, and easily installs Clojure dependencies (including ones you probably don't need, but it is easy).  [Debian sid has 1.7.1](http://packages.debian.org/sid/leiningen), which is the most recent stable version; Ubuntu 12.04 has this available in universe. Then you can follow the [lein instructions](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#readme).

Leiningen 2.0 is coming soon; maybe that will become available in a PPA when it is finalized.

Answer (score 1):

See recommendations from official site http://clojure.org/downloads . "Get Clojure via Leiningen" section.